# Unable to update a list item from a workflow task in C#

Tags: sharepoint-2010, state-machine

I am not getting any exceptions, but the code below is simply not working.  Any ideas?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {            
        using (SPWeb web = this.workflowProperties.Web) {
        try {
          SPListItem item = web.Lists["NewHireFormsLibrary"].Items[workflowProperties.ItemId - 1];
          item["Field 1"] = "Gotcha!!!";
          item.Update();

          LogHistory("Information", "Workflow indexing complete.  " + item["Field 1"], "");
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             LogHistory("Error", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
         }
   }
)};
```

Comment: Okay, just an update.  This works if I apply the item to a non-infopath field.  How can i update an infopath field?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not referencing the field by it's Internal Name, which is how you have to reference fields when accessing them with the `SPListItem`'s indexer.  Try something like

```
item["Field_x0020_1"] = "Gotcha!!!";
```

and it *should* work.  Note that Internal names never contain spaces and are replaced by their hex character string like above.

Comment: Im going to try it, but how do I figure out what the internal name is?

Comment: It didn't work, actually.  Does it matter that it is a infopath form document library?

Comment: I normally just write a quick app to loop through all the fields for a given list item and print out SPField.InternalName.  Optionally, you could get each fields ID (Guid) and use that instead of the internal name.  Your infopath fields might have some kind of prefix or something prepended to the internal name (though I'm not very familiar with infopath integration, so I can't say for sure).

Comment: SharePoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com/) reveals the internal field names and much more.